# How do I create an Endpoint for an external service running on the same localhost outside of K8s cluster?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, kubernetes-service, kube-proxy

I am using Docker for Windows (docker-desktop) which ships with a small single node kubernetes instance. I have a scenario where my pods needs to communicate with some external services running on the same localhost(windwos 10 machine), but outside of the k8s cluster.

I know that I can use `kubernetes.docker.internal` from within the cluster to reach my `node/localhost`. But unfortunately the pods has some default connection string within the image which I don't want to change - say the pods are by default trying to connect to a dns string - "my-server". So in my scenario, I want to define a K8s service with name "my-server" which has an Endpoint reference to kubernetes.docker.internal so that the kube-proxy will route that correctly to my localhost which is my windows 10 machine.

Is this somehow possible? I have already checked [this](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/kubernetes-best-practices-mapping-external-services) solution, but it talks about external services running on some other node or cloud. I am also considering the local machine hostname as an ExternalName, but this is not entirely reliable in dns resolution for my usecase. So I really want to use the `kubernetes.docker.internal` as a service endpoint. Any thoughts?

Comment: It'd be better to make the server hostname configurable in your code than to try to hack around it at the Kubernetes layer.

Comment: Hi @DavidMaze, thanks for the reply, yes, that is what I am going to suggest to our team. But at this point of time we are working with a docker image that is already built that way and I dont want to change it now. Hence I asked this question to reuse that "my-server" as a service alias name to the actual service running natively on the host. Does it mean we cannot define a service that can point to "kubernetes.docker.internal" as the backend?

Answer (score 3):

One trick I've used was to forward an internal IP address back to 127.0.0.1
It worked perfectly.

```sh
# linux
sudo iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p all -d 10.0.100.100 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1

# osx 
sudo ifconfig lo0 alias 10.0.100.100
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know that I can use `kubernetes.docker.internal` from within the
>   cluster to reach my `node/localhost`.

If you're sure you can reach your windows machine via this address, there are some solutions.

**Kubernetes** allows you to modify `/etc/hosts` file in any `Pod`. I assume `kubernetes.docker.internal` resolves to some IP. If you know this IP you can add it to `/etc/hosts` file used by containers in a `Pod`. This way can map any domain name you want to this IP. For details, please refer to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) article in **kubernetes documentation**.

---

If for some reason IP cannot be used in this case, there is one more solution. You can modify the default behaviour of your **core-dns** by using `rewrite` plugin. It's nicely described in [this](https://coredns.io/2017/05/08/custom-dns-entries-for-kubernetes/) article.